# Content delivery: Alternatives to SHOUTcast

Tags: video-streaming

I've been using [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) and [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools) for several years now, to deliver audio and Video content.

I wonder what kind of alternatives do I have to those two, especially when streaming video. On the client side, what software can I choose from to stream to those servers live?

Making the streams available with Flash would be great, but that's maybe another story. We're still using [EdCast](http://users.tpg.com.au/radiorio/), which is kinda dead by now, Shoutcast DSP plugin is not an option, as this tends to crash, etc. Are there any alternatives to that, when livestreaming video?

I'm using [Liquidsoap](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/) for content generation, mixing, etc. It should work with Icecast, Liquidsoap and if possible SHOUTcast.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Flumotion Streaming Server: http://flumotion.net/ a number of bright minds in the gnome video community have been working on this for a while. It can transcode streams on the fly in multiple formats and comes with free java based clients to play open codec encoded video (so it works out of the box, just like flash).

Comment: Definitely worth to take a look. I need it to run without a GUI, though.

Comment: The server runs without a gui, the gui is just for setting things up / administrating things.